# action use: doesn't update

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I have svelte component when i'm trying to create form and also js file with form logic.
I want to use action in order to register each input inside the form.
The mount and unmount works well, but the update doesn't seem to work.

code:
https://svelte.dev/repl/dd57165f12ce4029b905dcfcefb6e783?version=3.22.3

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not meant to work this way...

```js
return {
  update(value) {
    fields.update((n) => ({ ...n, [name]: value }))
  },
  destroy() {
    // ...
  },
}
```

Note the documentation and example

> An action can have parameters. If the returned value has an update method, it will be called whenever those parameters change, immediately after Svelte has applied updates to the markup.

```html
<script>
    export let bar;

    function foo(node, bar) {
        // the node has been mounted in the DOM

        return {
            update(bar) {
                // the value of `bar` has changed
            },

            destroy() {
                // the node has been removed from the DOM
            }
        };
    }
</script>

<div use:foo={bar}></div>
```

the `bar` parameter is passed in to the `foo` function and bound to the element, that means it is already reactive. In your example, your are passing value, which is a static value taken at the time of mount, which will not update.

You can add the event listener directly to the `node` in your register function

```js
const onUpdate = (event) => {
    fields.update((n) => ({ ...n, [name]: event.target.value }))
}

node.addEventListener('change', onUpdate);
```

There may be a *sveltier* way to bind the value, which would then allow you to use your update function, but this works.